# May I redirect someone's "shlichut" money?

Tags: shlichus-agency

When I go to Israel, inevitably, several people give me shlichut money to donate to needy at the Kotel.

If I can't get to the Kotel, am I allowed to donate this money to anyone else at any other location? Or should I return the money to the donator?

Assume that the donor said, "Give this money to someone at the Kotel," but did not specify either way that I can donate this elsewhere. Knowing something about the people's general personalities, I assume that they don't mind if I donate to a poor person in Tirat Tzvi.

Comment: The general rule for fulfilling the mitzvah of shlichut (agency) is that you comply with the instructions of the one who sent you. Hopefully, prior to taking on the responsibility, the agent has clarified with the sender any contingencies if the mission changes. This is actually discussed at length by the Lubavitcher Rebbe as it applies in halacha in Sefer HaShlichut.

Comment: You can always give the money to someone else to bring to the Kosel for you. A Shliach can make another Shliach.

Comment: At first glance when a man says to give at the kotel it is Davka. There is a Mishna in gittinתן גט לאשתי במקום פלוניversus הרי הוא במקום פלוני

Comment: @DonielF This may sound strange, but assume that I am travelling solo and don't know anyone that I can trust to do the job, esp. on Tish'a B'Av. (Read the morning haftarah to understand this bad joke ;-)

Comment: I would be surprised if they have online donations

Comment: @DonielF "A Shliach can make another Shliach." It depends upon whether there was any stipulation by the one originally appointing the 1st shaliach. If they specifically wanted only them to personally deliver, to appoint someone else, even though halachically valid, would violate the terms of the 1st agency.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Of course I’m assuming that he didn’t stipulate otherwise, in which case we rely on שליח עושה שליח. Even though we usually say אין רצוני שיהא פקדוני ביד אחר, this isn’t a פקדון, as he specifically wanted him to give it to someone, rather than to hold onto it for him, so that’s not a concern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of appointing another shaliach. Please view the latest edits. For purposes of this question, assume that I don't know anyone whom I can appoint. Even if I did, how could either the donor or I know guarantee that the money was given to someone at the kotel by someone else, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

When somebody gives you money to donate on their behalf to a needy cause, you are simply their messenger to do so and you are not allowed to use that money for anything else.
In fact, once they have taken a physical action towards getting that money to that cause, such as giving the money to someone to take for them, they should also not change it since they have already dedicated it to that cause.

Hence this really should be stipulated to begin with. Before they give you the money, you should stipulate that you might not be able to get the money to that specific cause and request that they stipulate what you should do with it in that case.

Comment: Welcome to MY! Would you consider adding sources to your answer? Since we don't know you in person, this would add much to the credibility of your answer.

Comment: This is a interesting guess. Not too useful for anyone who doesn't know you enough to trust your guesses, though. After all we all could write guesses of what the answer is.

Comment: You also haven't exactly answered my question addressing the specific situation. I asked what someone should do if he cannot get to the specific place that the donor specified.